# PostgreSQL: Replace string from specific position to end of string

Tags: postgresql

I have the following string:

```
String 1: abcde?dafsdfdsfsd
String 2: absdfcde?dafsdfdsfsdsfdsdfd
```

Want to remove anything after "?"

Expected output:

```
String 1: abcde
String 2: absdfcde
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
with my_data(col) as (
values
    ('abcde?dafsdfdsfsd'),
    ('absdfcde?dafsdfdsfsdsfdsdfd')
)

select split_part(col, '?', 1)
from my_data;

 split_part 
------------
 abcde
 absdfcde
(2 rows)
```